# Jumps out from For loop c++

Tags: c++

I have a little program that will simulate a jukebox. 
I have a class for all songs, and a class for all albums that contain the Song classes.

In this function I will print out all songs in the Album vector and use the iterator to give every song a number. 1.2.3.4.etc

When I declare "int i" in the second for loop, then ofcourse after every album the int "i" will become 0 again. But when I declare it before all For loops, I only get the first album printed.

How come?

```
 void Jukebox::createList() {
    int i = 0;

    for (auto idx : albvec)
    {

        // Write out the songs
        for (i; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++)
        {
            cout << i+1 << "  " << idx.getSongvec()[i].getArtist() << " - ";
            cout << idx.getSongvec()[i].getTitle() << " ";
            Time t = idx.getSongvec()[i].getDuration();
            printTime(t);
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When you don't reinitialise the value of `i` in the inner loop, the value persists from the old loop - this means that for the second album, your value of `i` may be greater than `idx.getNrSongs()` so it just doesn't run any code from that loop.

Comment: @hnefatl thats true, my next album is only 14 songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `i` has the same scope as your first for loop, so it won't be reinitialize at the beginning of your second for loop. This means 
 that after the first for loop is finished you'll end up with `i` being greater than `idx.getNrSongs()` and no longer satisfying any of the further conditions.

```
int i = 0;

for (auto idx : albvec)
{

    // Write out the songs
    for (i; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "  " << idx.getSongvec()[i].getArtist() << " - ";
        cout << idx.getSongvec()[i].getTitle() << " ";
        Time t = idx.getSongvec()[i].getDuration();
        printTime(t);
        cout << endl;
    }
    // at this point, i is now greater than idx.getNrSongs().
    // since the scope of i is not local to the for loop, it's
    // value will be kept for the next for loop iteration! Meaning
    // if i ends at 5 for example on the first loop, it will start
    // with 5 on the second loop
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I have solved it by initializing the value of i as usual, and have another int inizialized outside the for loops and add it by one after each loop.

Answer (score 4):

> When I declare "int i" in the second for loop, then ofcourse after every album the int "i" will become 0 again. But when I declare it before all For loops, I only get the first album printed.
>
> How come?

When the inner loop is executed for the second album, the value `i` is not being reset to zero.

Change

```
    for (i; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++)
```

to

```
    for (i = 0; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++)
```

---

One of the good coding practices is to keep the scopes of variables as small as you can get away with. Hence, it will be better for your use case to use:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop: `for (i; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++)` should be: `for (i = 0; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++)`. Basically the `for` loop consists of the initialization, continue condition, and incrementation part, your initialization part, does not reset the value of `i`. Basically your value of `i` is remembered, so when the first album is done, the continue condition is not met when the next album is processed, so you will not enter the next albums inner loop unless, that album has more songs than the previous.

Comment: This will reset the iterator "i" every a new album is to be printed

Comment: Hmm, thats how it programmed it in the first place but it keeps reseting the value of i everytime a new album is to be printed. Now when i intialize it outside the for loop, i only get the first album printed.

Comment: The reason you only get the first album printed, when you initialize it outside the loop, is - as I said - that the value is never reset. You want all the albums songs to be printed in the number 1 to x, where x is the number of songs on the album right? so each album starts from 1?

Comment: Since `i` is only used in the body of the `for` loop then it should just be declared as part of the `for` statement like this: `for (int i = 0; i < idx.getNrSongs(); i++)` that way the lifetime/scope of `i` matches its usage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the songs uniquely numbered across all albums, then you need to create an additional variable  songNum to keep track of the song number.  Initialize this to zero out side both loops.  Then use (for int i = 0; i < ....) for the inner loop.  Change your print to use songNum instead of i, then remember to increment songNum.